# Spring boot Admin client issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, client, admin

Set up Spring boot Admin server version 2.1.1. There is Spring boot Jersey Microservice client for  admin server. getting issue that dispatcher servlet path bean not found. Please advise does Admin can have jersey client?

exception while jersey spring boot micro service start up:-
No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletPath' available:

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved now. Added Spring Boot starter web dependency. With both jersey and Spring MVC, actuator stopped working. Changed dispatcher servlet path by property:-spring.mvc.servlet.path.